# What do different SAML token validation calls specifically do?

Tags: security, rest, restful-authentication, wif, saml

I am trying to validate a SAML token that was created by our WIF-based custom STS inside a REST web service.

There are a couple of functions to do validation.  One is *SecurityTokenHandlerCollection.ValidateToken()* and another is *SamlSecurityTokenAuthenticator.ValidateToken()*.

Unfortunately the online Microsoft MSDN help for these classes and functions is worthless and does not describe at all what it is these functions are doing.

What are these functions validating and how are they doing it?  What are the differences between them?  Are they automatically looking up the certificate in the Windows Certificate Store to check the signature of the token, and validating the encrypted credentials object?  Because I don't pass a certificate name in anywhere.  Or are there other manual operations I need to do myself to validate the token?

I realize one returns a *ClaimsIdentityCollection* and the other returns a collection of *IAuthorizationPolicy* objects.  But is that the only difference?  I can't tell.

I can find plenty of information out on the web about the STS and claims and even validating claims, which I am doing successfully, but I can hardly find any information on validating the token itself to make sure it is one I created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases you don't need to worry about the token validation details. All this is taken care for you by WIF.

But if you really want to know, the best source of information is Vittorio's book: [http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Windows%C2%AE-Identity-Foundation-Dev/dp/0735627185](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627185)

There are some details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff359114.aspx

Another good way of learning is by looking at the extensions built to handle non-SAML tokens (e.g SWT). Download the samples [here](http://claimsid.codeplex.com) and look for the REST services.

Comment: I have Vittorio's book, but cannot find specific information about validating tokens, what ValidateToken() is doing, nor do I see a reference to SamlSecurityTokenAuthenticator at all.  There is some vague information on page 93.

Comment: In the other link you provide it says I must ensure the certificate used to create the token is one I trust by checking it's thumbprint or serial number. I've read lots and lots of articles on this topic and there is only one place I have ever seen that possibly gives an example or description of this.

Comment: (I'm not used to having enter accept these comments. sorry.)  Here is the link: http://www.leastprivilege.com/UsingTheNETAccessControlServiceWithGeneva.aspx

Comment: Are you saying SecurityTokenHandlerCollection.ValidateToken() automatically looks up the token in the Windows Certificate Store based on info in the SAML token, and validates the signature and credentials?

Comment: Cool!  Thank you!  First time I've heard of that.  I also just searched the Vittorio book again, and there is one description about what you just said under the Azure section on page 190, which I skipped as I'm not doing any Azure development.

Comment: Unless you are encrypting the token, there's no certificates to be stored in the RP (the web site). The token is a selk contained entity that WIF validates for you. You just need the "thumprint". Page 62 in Vittorio's book is where the explanation of the entire processing pipeline starts. Unless you need deep extensions into WIF, everything "just works" and you would not need to validate anything yourself.